# Video modal not working consistently in IOS and IE11

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have this site [here](http://cd12-nl-dev.indegene.com/), it has a vedio popup:

[image]

**ISSUE::-** If you click on the above video thumbnail , a popup will appear , now in chrome this popup appears just fine, but in IE and IOS sometimes when i click on the link, it just moves to the top of the page. (default anchor behavior). In IE sometimes the popup opens and the video plays , then when i hard refresh the video does't play anymore.

**MY DIAGNOSIS::-** Alot of the plugins for this vedio modal are being loaded via require.js , such as `modalvideotrigger.js`, the click handler for the video is being attached on line 179 of the modalvideotrigger.js file like so:

```
$jquery("a[data-videomodal='true']").bind("click", { "module": module }, module.onVideoModalClick);
```

If I attach a breakpoint in IE on this line when the video popup is not working, the line is never hit.

I have a file `script2.js` in which the plugin is initialized like so:

```
require(["/Content/Shared/Core/js/RequireJs/config.js"], function () {
    require(["core/Mylan/mylanmanager", "core/Mylan/Modules/moduleUtils", "core/Mylan/Modules/modalvideotrigger"],
        function (mylanmanager, utils, modalvideotrigger) {

                var settings = {
                    AspectRatio: '16:9',
                    EnableProgressionTracking: false,
                    ProgressionTrackingReportingInterval: 0,
                    ProgressionTrackingCategory: 'video',
                    ProgressionTrackingAction: 'playback',
                    ProgressionTrackingLabelOverride: null,
                    ProgressionTrackingValueOverride: 0,
                    GtmEventName: 'VideoProgressionTracking'
                };

                mylanmanager.registerModule(new modalvideotrigger("Hero Video Slide", settings));
        }
    );
});
```

My config file for require.js looks like so:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Content",
    paths: {
        "core": "Shared/Core/js",
        "jquery": "Shared/Core/js/jQuery/jquery",
        "jqueryui": "Shared/Core/js/jQuery/jquery-ui",
        "jquerytooltabs": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.tool.tabs",
        "modernizr": "Shared/Core/js/Modernizr/modernizr",
        "html5shiv": "Shared/Core/js/Html5Shiv/html5shiv",
        "jwplayer": "Shared/Core/js/JWPlayer/jwplayer",
        "bxslider": "Shared/Core/js/BxSlider/bxslider",
        "componentcatalog": "Shared/Core/js/Mylan/componentCatalog",
        "validate":"Shared/Core/js/jquery.validate.min",
        "unobtrusive": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min",
        "validatehooks": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.validate.hooks",
        "easing": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.easing.1.3",
        "waitforimages": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.waitforimages",
        "idletimer": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.idle-timer.min",
        "skrollr": "Shared/Core/js/Skrollr/skrollr.min",
        "skrollrmenu": "Shared/Core/js/Skrollr/skrollr.menu.min",
        "jquerymask": "Shared/Core/js/jquery.mask",
    },
    shim: {
        "bxslider": ["jquery"],
        "validate": ["jquery"],
        "unobtrusive": ["jquery", "validate"],
        "easing": ["jquery"],
        "validatehooks": ["jquery", "validate", "unobtrusive"],
        "waitforimages": ["jquery"],
        "idletimer": ["jquery"],
        "skrollrmenu": ["skrollr"],
        "jqueryui": ["jquery"],
        "jquerytooltabs": ["jquery"]
    },
    waitSeconds: 0 //25
});
```

I have tried increasing the waitsecounds to `waitSeconds: 25`, but the bug still persists.

Can somebody point me out as to whats going wrong here and why this video modal is not working consistently in IE11 and iOS?

Comment: You should be able to see what's happening with the required files by watching the network tab in the dev tools.  Maybe that could give some insight.

Comment: tested in IE 11.0.48 always work. what is your IE version?

Comment: @plonknimbuzz IE 11 , you can replicate the bug in chrome too sometimes by going to the network tab and changing the bandwidth to 3g or 2g

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb and say try it without the use of skrollr. Scrollers and modals have had mixed results across many browsers.

Comment: I can play video on my iphone (ip6 - ios 11.2.6) and ie 11.248